# An error occurred while executing Python code

Tags: qgis, python, quickosm

Getting an error while trying to launch QuickOSM saying that there was an error while trying to execute the Python code. I tried reinstalling the plugin, as well as updating QGIS, but I'm still getting the same error. I don't know what's going on and I'm hoping that I can get some help in figuring out what's going on.

Error stack trace:

````
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\quick_osm.py", line 249, in open_dialog
    dialog = Dialog()
  File "C:\Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\dialog.py", line 205, in __init__
    panel.setup_panel()
  File "C:\Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\quick_query_panel.py", line 134, in setup_panel
    self.update_history_view()
  File "C:\Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QuickOSM\ui\quick_query_panel.py", line 304, in update_history_view
    data = json.load(json_file, object_hook=as_enum)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)


Python version: 3.9.18 (heads/master:5eba59e, Feb  1 2024, 20:02:10) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.34.4-Prizren Prizren, decd43dc 

Python Path:
C:\Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\leastcostpath
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.34.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.34.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\grass\grass83\etc\python
C:\Users\sbrow\Documents
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.4\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.4\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/sbrow/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/sbrow/New folder```
````

Comment: That looks like your JSON file is empty

Comment: Can you open a ticket on GitHub ? You have an error in the JSON file in your own QGIS profile. Reinstalling the plugin or QGIS won't solve the problem. Thanks